# How do I successfully switch to XFS filesystem without corrupting any data?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, xfs

My MongoDB has recently been using lots of CPU on IO Wait. I believe by switching to XFS filesystem it should stop these issues. How can I successfully do this without corrupting any of my current data? I am on Ubuntu 18.04. My disk is currently ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to switch mongodb from ext4 to xfs:

It is simple : Add SECONDARY member with xfs, after the member finish with the replication  , you can switch to that member and remove the other with the ext4 fs.

if switching will solve the IO:
Perhaps adding more RAM will help more